# Reading hex values from and saving it to unsigned char array

Tags: c

I have a file containing HEX values in below format

```
0x020x000x000x000x000x000x680x000x000x000x020x000x000x000x000x00
```

I want to read these Hex Values and Save it as hex values in Unsigned char array in same format

Snippet of code(hex is char array, licensebin is unsigned char array)

```
fgets(hex, sizeof(hex), licenseFile);

used = 0;
while ((sscanf(hex+used, "%x", &licensebin[i]))==1)
{
    printf("%x", licensebin[i]);
    offset = 4;
    used += offset;
    i++;
}
```

Code above is not reading values correctly.

Comment: Is the file in binary hex or characters? `x020` is not a hex byte value, that would be `x02` or `x20`.

Comment: what is the type of licensebin?

Comment: @Pooya licensebin is of type unsigned char

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hex value is limited two character so in above example 0x02 is one value and 0x00 is another

Comment: As an aside, for error analysis I recommend either using a debugger or inserting debug output in strategic places in your program. It would probably show that the loop is only executed once and the first value is  32 and not 2. If gdb is too hard to learn for a small task in ISO C like this and you have access to a Windows box, just install the free Visual Studio edition and create a little ad-hoc project. The debugger there is very user friendly.

Comment: While I stick to my general recommendation to use a debugger and debug output, the printf (which was already in place) didn't help that much here; also my prediction about what the program did was wrong (because you use a hard-wired offset of 4 it could parse the next number alright, and went through the whole string). Did you figure out why, although the other numbers were read correctly, 0x68 was printed as a char value of 0x80? (Hint: "%x"; scanf reads 0x680; and you have an Intel processor).

Comment: Last recommendation, which can even save you from long debug sessions: **Heed thy warnings.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`scanf` function (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is *greedy* when it reads its data, meaning the `"%x"` format will read the leading zero from the *next* number as a final zero in the current number.

In the example you show, the first number it reads will be `0x020` and not `0x02`.

This can easily be solved by telling `sscanf` to only read four characters:

```
sscanf(hex+used, "%4x", &licensebin[i])
```

After you added the comment about `licensebin[i]` being an `unsigned char`, the correct format should actually be

```
sscanf(hex+used, "%4hhx", &licensebin[i])
```

The prefix `"hh"` tells `sscanf` that the argument is actually a pointer to an `unsigned char`. You *still* need to tell `sscanf` to read only max four characters, as it's still greedy.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? I think all answers are right (and Joachim was first).

Comment: Thanks it worked, I didn't know about the greedy nature of sscanf.

Comment: Just note, I'm pretty sure the hh size prefix isn't fully portable, for example I don't think Visual C supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change this:

```
while ((sscanf(hex+used, "%x", &licensebin[i]))==1)
{
```

To this:

```
unsigned int n;
while ((sscanf(hex+used, "0x%2x", &n)==1)
{    
    licensebin[i] = (unsigned char)n;
```

(Thanks to everyone reminding me of the type scanf expects when matching %x.)

This is intended to match the literal '0x' in your input and to limit the number of hex digits read to 2.

Alternatively change:

```
used = 0;
while ((sscanf(hex+used, "%x", &licensebin[i]))==1)
```

To:

```
used = 2;
unsigned int n;
while ((sscanf(hex+used, "%2x", &n)==1)
{    
    licensebin[i] = (unsigned char)n;
```

All this assumes the licensebin is something like:

```
char *hex = "0x020x000x000x000x000x000x680x000x000x000x020x000x000x000x000x00";
```

That is you literally have a '0' character, 'x' character etc. If your data is binary, you need a totally different approach.

Comment: I think you mean `char *hex= "0x020x000x000x000x000x000x680x000x000x000x020x000x000x000x000x00";`

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, Doh! Right, I'll fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below and it worked. Probably you need to define license as int when using %x instead of unsigned char:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int license[20];
    char* hex = "0x020x000x000x000x000x000x680x000x000x000x020x000x000x000x000x00";
    int used = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while((sscanf(hex+used,"%x",&license[i]))==1)
    {
        printf("%x",license[i]);
        i++;
        used += 4;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice. You could change license to an unsigned char array as requested by using a temporary int to hold the result from scanf. Feel free to copy that from my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to handle the hex string conversion is using `strtoul` with its ability to read/convert `base-16`. `strtoul` can be used along with a pointer to step through the input string providing conversion of each value found, and then simply moving the pointer to the beginning of the next value. Given your input, `strchr` is used to locate each `'x'` and then to convert the 2-characters that follow.

To aid in this process you can write a simple function that will provide all the error checking and validation of the conversions. Something like the following works well:

```
/** string to unsigned long with error checking */
unsigned long xstrtoul (char *p, char **ep, int base)
{
    errno = 0;

    unsigned long tmp = strtoul (p, ep, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == ULONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtoul");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*ep == p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

You need only minimal code to apply the function to all lines in your data file. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtol               */
#include <string.h> /* for strchr               */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN/INT_MAX      */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno                */

#define MAXL 256

unsigned long xstrtoul (char *p, char **ep, int base);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    char line[MAXL] = {0};
    unsigned values[MAXL] = {0};
    int base = argc > 2 ? atoi (argv[2]) : 16;
    size_t i, idx = 0;

    if (!fp) { /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failen '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file (up to MAXL chars per-line) */
    while (fgets (line, MAXL, fp)) {

        char *p = line;
        char *ep = p;
        char digits[3] = {0};
        errno = 0;

        /* convert each string of digits into number */
        while (errno == 0) {

            /* skip any non-digit characters */
            if (!(p = strchr (p, 'x'))) break;
            strncpy (digits, ++p, 2);
            digits[2] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

            /* convert string to number */
            values[idx++] = (unsigned)xstrtoul (digits, &ep, base);

            if (errno || idx == MAXL) {   /* check for error */
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXL values reached.\n");
                break;
            }
            p += 2;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    /* print results */
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" values[%2zu] : 0x%02x\n", i, values[i]);

    return 0;
}

/** string to unsigned long with error checking */
unsigned long xstrtoul (char *p, char **ep, int base)
{
    errno = 0;

    unsigned long tmp = strtoul (p, ep, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == ULONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtoul");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*ep == p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

**Input Files**

```
$ cat dat/hex3.txt
0x020x000x000x000x000x000x680x000x000x000x020x000x000x000x000x00
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_xstrtoul_simple dat/hex3.txt
 values[ 0] : 0x02
 values[ 1] : 0x00
 values[ 2] : 0x00
 values[ 3] : 0x00
 values[ 4] : 0x00
 values[ 5] : 0x00
 values[ 6] : 0x68
 values[ 7] : 0x00
 values[ 8] : 0x00
 values[ 9] : 0x00
 values[10] : 0x02
 values[11] : 0x00
 values[12] : 0x00
 values[13] : 0x00
 values[14] : 0x00
 values[15] : 0x00
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.